# Can you solve ode with variable constants?

Tags: python, numpy, physics, ode, odeint

I have a uni assignment where I have to create model for lunar descent. Model starts from a height and descends with two engines who are placed under an angle. 
This is the part of the code I have issues with:

```
F1 = f*np.array([1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #f-thrust in newtons
F2 = f*np.array([1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #F1 and F2 regime of engines for each time step(percentage of thrust)

t = np.arange(0, np.size(F1), dt) #time domain

#a,b - angles of engines according to global coordinate system
#s0x, v0x, s0y, v0y, fi0, omg0 - initial values
#m - mass
def model_engine(u, t):
    x, vx, y, vy, phi, w = u   
    d1 = vx
    d2 = (1/(m))*(F1*np.cos((a)) - F2*np.cos((b)))
    d3 = vy
    d4 = (1/(m))*(F1*np.sin((a)) + F2*np.sin((b))) + g 
    d5 = w
    d6 = (F1*np.cos(a)*(h/2) - F1*np.sin(a)*(w/2) + F2*np.sin(b)*(w/2) - 
             F2*np.cos(b)*(h/2))/((1/12)*(m)*h**2)
    return np.array([d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6])

U = odeint(model_engine, [s0x, v0x, s0y, v0y, fi0, omg0], t)
```

1. I dont know how to implement diferent F1 for each timestep in definition? I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`
   The same is with the variable mass, it depends on engines regime.
2. The solution gives angle of spacecraft (d6). Equations written in this way always give a and b as 45 degrees which is obviously not correct because the spacecraft rotates. How can I take solution (angle) from previous step and put it in current step? See photo for clarification

[image: photo]

Comment: Please have a look at how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method for the first question: How to implement a variable coefficient? The thrust is assumed to be a step function of `t` only. It is obtained by interpolation of the given thrust commands at the corresponding time. The interpolation function is passed to `model_engine` function as an additional argument.

The model is simplified to a vertical lander having a constant mass.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.integrate import odeint

from scipy.constants import g

def model_engine(u, t, thrust, mass):
    y, vy = u 

    dydt = vy
    dvy_dt = 1/mass * thrust(t) - g 

    return np.array([dydt, dvy_dt])


# Thrust definition:
F_values = g*np.array([1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1.5, 1]) # f-thrust in newtons
timesteps = np.linspace(0, 10, np.size(F_values)) # timesteps used to defined the thrust

thrust = interp1d(timesteps, F_values, kind='previous', fill_value='extrapolate')

# Solve
s0y, v0y = 102, 0
m0 = 1
t_span = np.linspace(0, 1.2*timesteps[-1], 111)
U = odeint(model_engine, [s0y, v0y], t_span, args=(thrust, m0))

# Graphs
plt.figure();
plt.plot(t_span, U[:, 0], label='altitude')
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', label='moon surface');
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.legend();

plt.figure();
plt.plot(t_span, thrust(t_span), label='thrust');
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.legend();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful !